# Getting Time from DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime, time

This is confusing, all I want is the Time from DateTime ?

here is my code:

```
clsdbo_RR.DateRecd = reader["DateRecd"] is DBNull ? null : (DateTime?)reader["DateRecd"];
clsdbo_RR.TimeRecd = reader["TimeRecd"] is DBNull ? null : reader["TimeRecd"].ToString("hh:mm:ss");
```

My date appears as date correctly but the time is not showing up?

```
 private Nullable<DateTime> m_TimeRecd;

public Nullable<DateTime> DateRecd
{
    get
    {
        return m_DateRecd;
    }
    set
    {
        m_DateRecd = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is lacking info. What's `reader["TimeRecd"]` value and type? And about `clsdbo_RR.TimeRecd`? Where is it not showing up?

Comment: What is the data type of `reader["TimeRecd"]`?

Comment: Maybe the time wasn't entered into database.

Comment: @Magnetron reader is SqlDataReader and it is in a public static class

Comment: @Magnetron  private Nullable<DateTime> m_TimeRecd;

Comment: @ChrisR He didn't ask what `reader` is.  He and I both asked what data type `reader["TimeRecd"]` is.  Note the difference.  We know what `reader` is.

Comment: @Amy The data type for TimeRecd is (time(7), null) in SQL.

Comment: Note, if you aren't showing am/pm information, you should use `HH` rather than `hh`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *strongly* suspect that your `reader["TimeRecd"]` returns `object`, that's why you need to cast it to `DateTime` (or `DateTime?` as you did) first before you call `ToString` method. Without casting, it probably calls `object.ToString` method, not `DateTime.ToString`.

If your `clsdbo_RR.TimeRecd` is `string`, you just need to use `(DateTime?)reader["TimeRecd"].ToString("hh:mm:ss")` instead like;

```
clsdbo_RR.TimeRecd = reader["TimeRecd"] is DBNull ? 
                     null : (DateTime?)reader["TimeRecd"].ToString("hh:mm:ss");
```

Comment: The time wasn't in the stored procedure call. Note to self, always set breakpoint on reader to see if data is actually there first before posting. Sorry guys.

Comment: I also should add that SQL type Time(7) is Timespan in C# and not DateTime.